# Why write form component not use in controller-LARAVEL?

Tags: php, laravel

My controller as below;

```
public function getFunction() {
$kelime = "<div class='col-2 pr-0'>
           {!!Form::number('sales_price', null , ['class'=>'form-control' , 'min' => 0, 'placeholder' => '0.00']) !!}
                   </div>";
        echo $kelime;
}
```

Why not get output. i think i can not write this part =  `{!!Form::number('sales_price', null , ['class'=>'form-control' , 'min' => 0, 'placeholder' => '0.00']) !!}`

Comment: Your controller **should not** hold any html this is what the view pages are for...

Comment: but I have to use it. I'm working with ajax.

Comment: No you don't...

Comment: You're just `echo`'ing the string. Should be parsed by Blade I guess to make `{!! !!}` work. But then again like @Option said: you shouldn't.

Comment: MVC = Model View Controller... Not just Model Controller Framework ^_^ any html needs to be within your view. I'd suggest looking up some laravel / ajax tutorials for futher insight.

Comment: I need to generate output form  input with my ajax. I KNOW LOGIC MVC. how do i do this?.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right solution. But if you need to do this in this way then you can use this code

```
public function getFunction() {
$kelime = "<div class='col-2 pr-0'><input type='number' name='sales_price' class='form-control' min='0' placeholder='0.00' />
                   </div>";
        echo $kelime;
}
```

You can not use blade expression in the controller. Remove the blade expression from the controller and write pure HTML.